# Cant start nginx with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rubygems, passenger

i have nginx compiled with passenger, and i am trying to start it, i get the following error:

**Starting nginx: nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/home/trusteer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'passenger_root' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'passenger_root' directive, whichever is applicable. (-1: Unknown error)**

I have the passenger gem installed, but the agents folder is indeed missing, what could be the reason for that ? I have this gem installed in other machine (i didnt install it there, its old), and i see that the gem include the agents directory, and its the same gem version (3.0.19).

what could be the reason for this issue ?

Comment: did you use the passenger-install-nginx-module command to install the nginx?

Comment: Ruby -v ? passenger gem version?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux],
passenger (3.0.19)

Comment: did you followed @cenyongh comment?

Comment: @cenyongh - i think i did once, i understood that it should have fixed the agents issue, but yea, i ran it.

Comment: @gal have you try to remove the nginx and the passenger gem. And reinstall them all from the beginning again.

Comment: @cenyongh - i didnt install nginx, i have an executable of it compiled with passenger, and i tried to reinstall the passenger gem, still didnt contain the agents directory.

Comment: @gal it looks like the newest version 4, didn't contain an agent directory. Take a look at the installation guide from passenger, https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu. Maybe the method which is works for version 3 is no longer works for version 4.

Comment: I dont need version 4, the thing is, that is another machine, i saw that the gem include the agents directory, and its the same gem version, 3.0.19.

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure has changed in Phusion Passenger 4. Most likely, your Nginx is compiled for Phusion Passenger 3. Nginx *must* be compiled for the same version of Phusion Passenger that the passenger_root points to.